# Allow access to a specific php file in CI root

Tags: php, .htaccess, codeigniter

I created a test.php in my root. and wanted it to be accessible but its giving me a 404 error. Please see below for my .htaccess config.

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\.domain\.com [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.domain.com/$1 [R=301,NC,L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index.php/$1 [L]
```

I tried adding "RewriteCond $1 !^(test.php)" above the rewriteRule but its still not accessible. Can anyone give me an advice on how I can make the test.php accessible in a browser, I want to access it in a browser by going to this URL: www.domain.com/test.php

Thanks in advance!

Comment: If you comment out both rules then can you access `www.domain.com/test.php`?

Comment: removed the htaccess and I can still access the CI index.php, but I have a Internal Server Error in test.php

Comment: If the error is without htaccess, then there's a problem with test.php, I suppose

Comment: I dont think the test.php is the problem because I only added one code which is "<?php echo 'test'; ?>".

Comment: could there be an additional htaccess in the system that's causing problems...

Comment: Check your error.log to check if there is anything there.

Comment: I use the default htaccess of CI. the only one I been editing is the htaccess in the root, which has the code above. Not really sure what Im missing here. because if I tried to access .txt or .html files they are fine.

Comment: In that case, are you using www before your domain name when testing these changes?

Comment: only have this on my error.log:

[03-Dec-2013 18:01:18 America/Chicago] PHP Fatal error:  Call to undefined function base_url() in /home/[username]/public_html/application/errors/error_404.php on line 7

Comment: so, from your previous comment, I gather that the only htaccess in your directory is the one for CI, in your root, absolutely no other htaccess files?

Comment: for the error you've written, you should load the url helper... $this->load->helper('url');

Comment: no worries for that. it only happen earlier when I changed and testing the htaccess. but when I put it back to my old htaccess that problem is not showing up. and yes, all the needed helper is loaded. No problem with the CI part. only issue is I wanted to access that specific file outside of CI to communicate with github.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/42464/discussion-between-naveed-hasan-and-myke-solidum)

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond $1 !^(index\.php|images|css|test\.php)
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ ./index.php/$1 [L]
```

Every request will be sent to your index.php except those mentioned in RewriteCond, i.e., css, images and test.php

Comment: Thanks for your reply but still dont work. I tried changing to this only and its showing 404 page in test.php

Comment: Can you access it without having an htaccess file at all?

Comment: yes, I changed everything and just copy and paste your code above.

Answer (score 0):

Replace your first two lines with the following.

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^site\.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^ http://www.%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [R=302,L,NE]
```

Also your index.php should be accesible with or without that code so it's not needed.